# Mocha with serenity-js

Tags: serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity, serenity-js

As per the conversation https://medium.com/p/b06559b35459/info,

When I tried to

```
import `{describe, it} from '@types/mocha'
```

I see

```
Error:-
/node_modules/@types/mocha/index.d.ts' is not a module
```

As per the example in serenity-js project :- serenity-js/examples/todomvc-protractor-mocha

```
serenity: {
    dialect: 'mocha',
    crew: [
        crew.serenityBDDReporter(),
        crew.consoleReporter(),
        crew.Photographer.who(_ => _
            .takesPhotosOf(_.Tasks_and_Interactions)
            .takesPhotosWhen(_.Activity_Finishes)
        )
    ]
},
```

When added in the master branch protractor.conf.js, It does not pick up the feature file.
https://github.com/serenity-js/tutorial-from-scripts-to-serenity.git

Can you please let know how do i use mocha in the project?

Answer (score 0):

[Mocha's](https://mochajs.org/#hooks) `describe` and `it` functions are defined in the [global scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Global_variables) and `@types/mocha` definitions [reflect that](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/1254dcd7c0c6ab32c58d25cf189bb3f03fc843ba/types/mocha/index.d.ts#L32-L43).
This means that you don't need to import them explicitly, as simply having the `@types/mocha` dependency installed makes those definitions available to the [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) compiler:

> By default all *visible* `“@types”` packages are included in your compilation. Packages in `node_modules/@types` of any enclosing folder are considered visible; specifically, that means packages within `./node_modules/@types/`, `../node_modules/@types/`, `../../node_modules/@types/`, and so on.
>
> -- [TypeScript manual](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types).

---

Please note that using Serenity/JS with Mocha is described in the [Serenity/JS Handbook](http://serenity-js.org/mocha/automation.html).

You might also find the [example project](https://github.com/jan-molak/serenity-js/tree/2864f2ff5532bdfcc200c3c6002be2b074b37fcd/examples/todomvc-protractor-mocha) useful.